# A free category on the graph of flights. What idea is captured?

Tags: category-theory, free-groups, adjoint-functors

I disagree with an exercise in my cat theory book.

In exercise 5.1.2.35 it asks me what idea is captured by the free category on $G$, where $G$ is the graph whose vertices are all the European cities and whose arrows are airplane flights connecting the cities.

The solution argues that this captures the idea of flight itineraries. However to me it just captures rubbish. You would have morphisms of the like

```
Amsterdam → Moscow → Amsterdam → Genova → Amsterdam → Paris → Amsterdam → Rome → Amsterdam
```

And now, this is not a composition on many morphism, this is a possible path on the underlying graph which was stuffed inside $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{G}}(\mathtt{Amsterdam}, \mathtt{Amsterdam})$.

Comment: Could you say what book you're using?

Comment: David Spivak Category Theory for the Sciences

Comment: You say this like being "rubbish" is self-evident, but I honestly can't see anything disagreeable with what you've written. You need to explain your point of view; your words don't convey it clearly to someone who doesn't already know what you mean.

Comment: Well, an itinerary always start from a city and goes through a set of cities and ends in a city. In a free category, in the case illustrated, we start in a city, we fly over possibly infinite cities and then we land in the same city.

Comment: Also you have other cities like Moscow inside the homset, but you never touch the actual Moscow object. That's not an itinerary to me.

Comment: It sounds like your question is just a disagreement about the meaning of the word "itinerary", not an actual mathematical question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as Eric Wofsey noted, "It sounds like your question is just a disagreement about the meaning of the word 'itinerary', not an actual mathematical question."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this interpretation of the category, the intention is that you should read $\hom(A, B)$ as being the answer to the question "Which itineraries start in city $A$ and end in city $B$?"

Ideas like whether or not an itinerary passes through another city is expressed in different terms. For example, given an itinerary $f$ from Amsterdam to London, the assertion:

- $f$ goes from Amsterdam to London by way of Moscow

expressed in category language would be the issertion

- $f$ factors into a product $g \cdot h$, where $h$ is an itinerary starting in Amsterdam and ending in Moscow, and $g$ is an itinerary starting in Moscow and ending in London

Comment: Thanks, I agree with the first part. But when you say "factor into a product" I would imagine you need additional algebra to devise such factorization. You could say that the two morphisms have a similar name but the rules on how to factor them are not part of the category structure.

Comment: @gurghet: A category, by definition, *does* have such an algebra. In the definition of a free category on a graph, the product of a path starting at $A$ with a path ending at $A$ is the path you get by concatenating them.

Comment: Ok, I guess I’m missing something in the act of the creation of morphisms like the long one I’ve written above. Initially to me it just looks like a long label that this morphism have. I fail to see how does the name of the morphism relates to the other objects of the category. How do I know that `Moscow` inside the morphism is the same `Moscow` $\in \mathcal{G}$

Comment: @Gurghet Huh? Where else did Moscow come from in the morphism, other than being an object that was the endpoint of one factor in the morphism?

Answer (score 3):

From what I read in the comments, I think you misunderstand something about the free category generated by a graph $G$.

---

Because *graph* can have very different meaning depending on who you are talking about, let us agree that it means a *directed non involutive multigraph*, that is two sets $G_0,G_1$ and two functions $s,t:G_1\rightrightarrows G_0$. In the book's example, $G_0$ is the set of european cities, $G_1$ the sets of flights between these, $s$ selects the start of the flight and $t$ selects the destination of the flight.

From what I read in your post, I guess you understand that objects of the free category $F(G)$ are the elements of $G_0$ (the cities), and that the morphisms $x\to y$ in $F(G)$ are the finite path from $x$ to $y$ in $G$, meaning the finite sequences $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ with $$s(e_1)=x,s(e_2)=t(e_1),\dots,s(e_n)=t(e_{n-1}),t(e_n)=y$$
I guess you also understand that identity morphisms are given by the empty sequences.

From what I read in the comments, I'm not sure you understand **composition**: this is given by concatenation. So that composing $(e_1,\dots,e_n) : x \to y$ with $(f_1,\dots,f_m): y \to z$ gives $(e_1,\dots,e_n,f_1,\dots,f_m): x \to z$. In particular, it means that 
$$ (e_1,\dots,e_n) = (e_n)\circ \dots \circ (e_1) $$
where $(e_i): s(e_i) \to t(e_i)$ is the sequence of length $1$ defined by the edge $e_i$.

Coming back to the book's example, given a flight $\mathbf{AF110}: \mathrm{Paris} \to \mathrm{Oslo}$ and a flight $\mathbf{SK042} : \mathrm{Oslo} \to \mathrm{Tromsö}$, the morphism $(\mathbf{AF110},\mathbf{SK042})$ in the free category is not just a meaningless name given to *some* morphism $\mathrm{Paris}\to\mathrm{Tromsö}$, it is indeed the *itinerary*
$$ (\mathbf{AF110},\mathbf{SK042}) = (\mathbf{SK042}) \circ (\mathbf{AF110}) $$ 
starting from Paris, landing in Oslo, then taking off from Oslo and finally landing in Tromsö. To go back to your example, there is indeed some itineraries from Amsterdam to Amsterdam, going all over Europe before coming back (although very few people would book that kind of itinerary I guess...)

---

(If I completely misunderstood your question, then sorry for the unecessary answer and I would have to agree with other people in that it is probably a matter of vocabulary and not about mathematics per se.)

Comment: Ok, so it actually helps thinking about the flights as morphisms. But I will have to think about it a little bit more. Thanks for your help! I will focus on how the composition function is defined and on how it works to give a meaning to the name o the morphisms.